# AngularJS: HTTP request is not responding after page is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, httprequest

I have an invoice page all values are based on AngularJS `ng-model`s (variables) so they are dynamic.

When I change text field DISCOUNT, all values change according to discount value (also call function `abc` repeatedly). This was working fine.

But now I have created a new function `loadadditionalvalues` inside function `abc` and request an HTTP call. First time this function work properly. However, when I type something in discount field, it requests, but never responds and gets hanged at my new function `loadadditionalvalues`.

```
function abc(){
    $scope.loadadditionalvalues = function (n,o,scope)
    {
        arr=[];
        $scope.isAppInitialized = false;
        var requestUrl = 'page_test.php?do=action_netvalues&action=ID' ;
        $http({
            url: requestUrl,
            method: 'GET'
        }).then(function(response){
            if(typeof response.data.ERROR_MSG !== 'undefined' || typeof response.data !== 'object' || typeof response.data.message !== 'undefined' || (typeof response.data.success !== 'undefined' && !response.data.success))
            {
                console.log("error ");
            }
            else
            {
                $scope.staffel_liste =response["data"];
            }
        });
    };

    $scope.loadadditionalvalues(null,null,scope);
}
```

Comment: have you tried adding an error callback: `.then(function(response){...}, function(error){...});` ?

Comment: it was not working. i tried.

Comment: How is the html code?

Comment: I think you are missing something... It should look like `$http(...).success(...).error(...)` (with proper handling within the `success` and `error`).

Comment: @FDavidov that's an [old syntax](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.7/docs/api/ng/service/$http). AngularJS 1.6+ uses `$http(...).then(...)` or `$http.get(...).then(...)`

Comment: are you sure your if condition works fine ? its strange that you dont get a response even if is eoor, also check the log on your back-end

Comment: @AlekseySolovey, **OLD** that works is better than **NEW** that does not. I'm using 1.5.8 and the suggested syntax works beautifully.

Comment: @FDavidov you need to show why it's better. Generally, it **way worse** than `.then` because it can't _return_ data from nested calls (`return $http(...)` inside another $http). `.success` is not any different and therefore shouldn't be used

Comment: @AlekseySolovey, nested HTTP requests? Hummm... It may be worth checking if such a scenario is really needed. See? **POWER** sometimes invite misbehavior (you can find many examples around the world; take politicians as the simples example). What I mean is, the fact that a language ALLOWS certain scenarios, it is sometimes highly recommended either to avoid them or to be extremely cautious when using them.